# NSlookup - Non-authoritative answer

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, ping, nslookup

When I nslookup behind our firewall i got Non-authoritative answer like this

---

Non-authoritative answer:

Name: sitius.com

Address: 173.44.39.70

---

but if i nslookup from public internet access i got this

---

name: sitius.com

address1: 173.44.39.70 173.44.39.70.static.quadranet.com

---

I can ping the sitius.com behind the firewall, I cant access their website. I did tracert , i stoped somewhere on the way to destination but out of our ISP. I got a msg like this:

---

Error Code 10060: Connection timeout

Background: The gateway could not receive a timely response from the website you are trying to access. This might indicate that the network is congested, or that the website is experiencing technical difficulties.

Date: 2/15/2013 3:50:37 PM [GMT]

Server: xxxx-fw-01.xxxxxx.com

Source: Firewall

---

is there anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two separate issues. One is that your ISP's firewall might block you from accessing the standard DNS port (53) of external sites, forcing you to use their DNS. This might or might not be a good thing, at least it explains the "Non-authoritative answer" and you *might* still be able to access the site itself.

The other thing is, why you cannot reach the remote website (port 80). It could be that the site is actually down or overloaded.

The real evil thing would be if your ISP's DNS is giving you not only "Non-authoriative", but *false* answer. This way they effectively block you from accessing the site. 
There is workaround for that, you can reconfigure your DNS manually, but it is fairly inconvenient.

I would ask your ISP about it and if you are not happy with their answer, change to an another ISP.

Comment: try to find any answer from this way